# Where do I ask about finding a framework that does a specific task, not asking for opinions?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I asked a question that got closed as off-topic because it dealt with finding a framework that meets certain criteria, which I now know is not a Stack Overflow topic. The closed-as-off-topic message and the help center did not suggest another Stack Exchange site to ask it on. Where on Stack Exchange or elsewhere do I ask a question like this:

> I've been researching frameworks for real-time collaboration web apps.
>   There are a ton of them out there and many are not very well
>   documented, so I feel like I'm just not getting anywhere. I've looked
>   at meteor, derby, mojito, and a lot of other ones, but I find it's
>   hard to get the information I need without going all out and becoming
>   an expert in each framework one at a time.
>
> Any experts know if there are real-time web app frameworks that that
>   have a development process like the following?
>
> 1. Start with a non-collaborative web app that is not tightly bound to any specific backend framework (like, say, some kind of
>      non-collaborative text editor that only relies on the server to hold
>      saved text files)
> 2. Mark the appropriate DOMElements and other objects/data fields as shared.
> 3. Set viewing permissions per user and DOMElement
> 4. Set editing permissions per user and object/data field
> 5. Optionally turn off auto-update and insert the update function in the appropriate spots in the javascript (still not sure if I want to
>      use auto-update or not).
>
> And then the final product would push changes whenever any shared data
>   field's value changes on the client of a user who has permission
>   (auto-update), or whenever you call the update function on an
>   object/data field.
>
> If there isn't something that auto-updates, I can live with calling
>   update all the time.
>
> Anyone know of a framework that's kind of like that?

Comment: When you're asking where to direct a question, you should enclose that question's content in block quotes to differentiate it from the question you're asking here to make the distinction clear. I've done so for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only site within Stack Exchange that will even remotely allow this type of question would be [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com), but their guidelines about the types of things you can post there are very strict. Be sure to review the guidelines in the help center there before posting.

Comment: Building on that: [libraries are on topic](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/8/450) and [What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/450)